# Calulate the eigenvalues and the possible states after measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

> An observable is given by $$\sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n|a_n\rangle\langle a_n | $$ Here $\langle a_n |a_m\rangle = \delta_{nm}$. What are the possible measurement results corresponding to the operator A and what are the possible states of the system after measurement?

How do I calculate the eigenvalues and states when only the operator is given and there is no $\psi$ the operator can act on?

Comment: How is there no $\psi$ the operator can act on? In that case, there is no physics.

Comment: Oh ok. So i use it to act on $\psi$ where $\psi$ is $a|+\rangle + b|-\rangle$?

Comment: It's okay for there to not be a wave function. If you're given a diagonal matrix (which is what you have!) then the eigenvalues are the numbers on the diagonal and the eigenvectors are the basis vectors. In basic quantum theory, those eigenvalues $\{a_n\}$ are the possible measurement values and the basis states ${|a_n\rangle}$ are the possible states after measurement, unless $a_m = a_n$ for $m \ne n$, in which case it's a little more complicated (because any vector in $\operatorname {span}(|a_m\rangle, ~|a_n\rangle)$ is an eigenvector).

Comment: So basically I just have to get the eigenvalues and eigenstates from the information given in the operator? Can you explain how i can read the values without using matrices?

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written the observable, let's call it $A$, indicates that $\vert a_n\rangle$ is a base of the Hilbert space you are acting on.

Try to do the calculation:

$$A \vert a_n \rangle = \sum_m a_m \vert a_m \rangle \langle a_m \vert a_n \rangle = \sum_m a_m \delta_{nm} \vert a_m \rangle= a_n \vert a_n \rangle  $$

and understand what you get.

Now apply the quantum postulates.

Comment: If we do this calculation we get $\sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n|a_n\rangle$. So will $\sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n$ be the eigenvalue and $|a_n\rangle$ the possible state?

Comment: @Paradox101 You have to be careful with your indices, see my edit.

Comment: Sorry i don't get it. Why have we included the kronecker delta and $|a_m\rangle $ ?

Comment: So if we want to get the eigenvalues and states we need to write it in matrix form and then find the eigenvalues using determinant?

Comment: How will we know when delta will be zero or one? There are N summations

Comment: @Paradox101 The thing is that you are given the spectral decomposition of the operator, so you can find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors by inspection. I think that this is nicely explained in Cohen-Tannoudji.

Comment: We haven't done spectral decomposition yet. So i can't use that fact

Comment: Does that then mean that $\sum_m a_m \delta_{nm} $ gives the eigenvalue and $|a_m\rangle$ the eigenstate?

Comment: You can't really conclude that you have a basis for the Hilbert space, since this is not even known. All you can say is that the operator is the zero operator when restricted to the orthogonal complement to the closed subspace generated by the given $N$ vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|a\rangle$ be any unit vector. Then the operator $|a\rangle\langle a|$ has the geometrical meaning of a projection onto the direction given by the vector $|a\rangle$ itself.
The condition $\langle a_m|a_n\rangle = \delta_{mn}$ is saying that every vector is a unit vector and they form an orthonormal system. Let $A$ be the given operator, then any multiple $\lambda$ of any of the given vectors $|a_n\rangle$ is such that
$$A\lambda|a_m\rangle = a_m\lambda|a_m\rangle,$$
which shows that $|a_m\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $a_m$. Therefore the point spectrum of $A$ is the set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ where repetitions are omitted (this is a set!). The states the system can be in are just the eigenvectors, which are just the given vectors $|a_m\rangle$.

Comment: But if we are just looking at the operator, where is the $|a_m\rangle$ coming from? Why are we even given the Kronecker delta?